# how would i make a value increase gradually over a second?

Tags: python

```
def stamina_regen(self, amount):
    if self.current_stamina < self.maximum_stamina:
        self.current_stamina += amount
    if self.current_stamina >= self.maximum_stamina:
        self.current_stamina = self.maximum_stamina
```

How would I make the amount increase over a second. In this case the amount would be 45 so I need it to increase by 45 every second. How would I do this?

Comment: You can use the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module to calculate how much time has passed then once it's been a second increase the amount

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

What if "stamina" was not a variable? What if it was a function of time?

```py
def __init__(self):
    self.stamina_rate = 45
    self.max_stamina = ...whatever...
    self.set_current_stamina(INITIAL_STAMINA)

def get_current_stamina(self):
    elapsed_time = time.clock_gettime() - self.stamina_epoch
    stamina = elapsed_time*self.stamina_rate + self.stamina_at_epoch
    if stamina > self.max_stamina:
        stamina = self.max_stamina
    return stamina
```

If some event happens that dings the character's stamina (I'm imagining that we're talking about a game here)...

```py
def set_current_stamina(self, new_stamina):
    self.stamina_at_epoch = new_stamina
    self.stamina_epoch = time.clock_gettime()
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use a thread:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class ...
    ...

    def statima_worker(self):
        while True:
            sleep(1)
            self.stamina_regen(45)
    
    def start_stamina_worker(self):
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.stamina_worker, daemon=True)
        self.thread.start()
```

the daemon arg means that the thread finish when the main thread reach the end.